# SignalR Core redis backplane - Is two way for scaling?

Tags: c#, redis, signalr, real-time, server-farm

We'll have a lot of data coming from outside of the signalR core server. So we're analyzing the best option to scale the servers for incoming data and publishing this data to users.

In the documentation we see that redis backplane is only used for publishing data between servers once one of them have received X data.

Is there something recommended to share the incoming data around the servers?

We've tried a timer to pop up the data from redis, but we don't know if this approach is correctly.